# Regex expression to check for all special W in sub domain in a URL

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a reges to check for subdomain - www in a URL where w can be any of the special char w like the -
LATIN SMALL LETTER W WITH GRAVE - ẁ.
I have to cover all such instances of the letter w included in following scripts-

Latin Extended Additional
Latin Extended-A
Latin Extended-C
Cyrillic
Greek etc.

I have used Unicode notation and written the following regex -

```
pattern = ur'[Ww\u1e80-\u1e89\u1e98\u0174\u0175\u2c72\u2c73\u0461\u047f\u1f60-\u1f67\u1f7d\u1fa0-\u1fa7\u1ff2-\u1ff7\uff37\u
ff57]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.'
```

Is there a better way to write this regex so that dont miss any of the special w characters?

Answer (score 0):

Why not split your string into blocks and then see if the subdomain has the chars in it instead of using a regular expression?

In Python 3, strings are really bytes arrays with an associated encoding, so you treat a string or part of one as blocks of bytes by encoding it.

```py
>>> "ẁ".encode()
b'\xe1\xba\x81'
>>> b"\xe1\xba\x81".decode("utf8")
'ẁ'
```

You can probably just split on `.` if you are using a simple example, and `urlparse` may help you

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

for atom in urlparse(url).netloc.split('.'):
    if www_test(atom):  # see if your atom works (has target www)
        # break or return discovered atom or url
else:  # did not find and break/return
```

This sounds like an exercise, but do beware that the rules around what is a valid URL are quite complex. Take caution to make sure you're really getting what you expect. (for example you may find the www is not in the first position or is absent)